# Python web scraping with requests - Got only a small part of data in the response

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get some financial data from this url:

http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/en/Negociation-History.aspx?Cat=24&IdLink=225

My code work only for a very small date interval (less than 19 days) but in the web site we are allowed to get *3 years of data!*.

My code is as follow:

```
import requests
import string
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# a simple helper function
def formatIt(s) :
    output = ''
    for i in s :
        if i in string.printable :
            output += i
    return output

# default url
uri = "http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/en/Negociation-History.aspx?Cat=24&IdLink=225"


def get_viewState_and_symVal (symbolName, session) :
    #session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get(uri)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) #soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    # let's get the viewstate value
    viewstate_val = soup.find('input', attrs = {"id" : "__VIEWSTATE"})['value']
    # let's get the symbol value
    selectSymb = soup.find('select', attrs = {"name" : "HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDValeur"})
    for i in selectSymb.find_all('option') : 
        if i.text == symbolName :
            symbol_val = i['value']
    # simple sanity check before return ! 
    try : 
        symbol_val
    except :
        raise NameError ("Symbol Name not found !!!")    
    else :
        return (viewstate_val, symbol_val)


def MainFun (symbolName, dateFrom, dateTo) :
    session = requests.Session()
    request1 = get_viewState_and_symVal (symbolName, session)
    viewstate = request1[0]
    symbol = request1[1]
    payload = {
        'TopControl1$ScriptManager1' : r'HistoriqueNegociation1$UpdatePanel1|HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$Image1',
        '__VIEWSTATE' : viewstate,
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDValeur' : symbol,  
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$historique' : r'RBSearchDate',
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DateTimeControl1$TBCalendar' : dateFrom,
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DateTimeControl2$TBCalendar' : dateTo,
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDuree' : r'6',
        'hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts' : r'1',
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$Image1.x' : r'27',
        'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$Image1.y' : r'8'
    }

    request2 = session.post(uri, data = payload)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(request2.content)
    ops = soup2.find_all('table', id = "arial11bleu")
    for i in ops : 
        try :
            i['class']
        except : 
            rslt = i
            break

    output = []
    for i in rslt.find_all('tr')[1:] :
        temp = []
        for j in i.find_all('td') :
            sani = j.text.strip()
            if not sani in string.whitespace :
                temp.append(formatIt(sani))
        if len(temp) > 0 :
            output.append(temp)

    with open("output.csv", "wb") as f :
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ';')
        writer.writerows(output)

    return writer



# working example
MainFun ("ATLANTA", "1/1/2014", "30/01/2014")

# not working example
MainFun ("ATLANTA", "1/1/2014", "30/03/2014")
```

Comment: It's possible that the site has scraping protection built into it.

Comment: @SimeonVisser : I'm not sure! but I already did some scraping in others pages in the same site and it work fine...

Comment: @alecxe : I got only a fraction of the data. Not all data that we get if we simulate the same request from the web page

Comment: @BilNash how do you know there are missing lines? Cannot reproduce it..could you provide a screenshot of missing lines and the data you've got in the csv? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I compare the content of the generated csv file with the result when I submit manually the form in : http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/en/Negociation-History.aspx?Cat=24&IdLink=225 For example : MainFun("ATLANTA", "1/1/2014", "30/06/2014") in my code generate only 10 line in the csv file, but if we simulate the same request manually in the web site we got much more than 10 line of data (choose security : ATLANTA, check "by period" case, start date : 1/1/2014, end date : 30/06/2014 then click submit). Thanks

Comment: @BilNash thanks, but you have `30/03/2014` as an end date in the code.

Comment: @alecxe it's just an example. with 30/03/2014 I got only 16 lines and a half in the csv file (60 lines in the web site).

Comment: @BilNash interesting, I'm getting 60 lines in the csv. Which `BeautifulSoup` version are you using btw?

Comment: @alecxe Beautiful Soup 4

Comment: @alecxe it's 4.3.2 exactly. what about your's please ?

Comment: @BilNash same here - 4.3.2 - and I've tried to switch different parsers - same result - 60, are you sure you are checking the correct `output.csv` file?

Comment: @alecxe It seems like there is a problem somewhere in my configuration in Windows. I ran the same code this morning in a debian virtual machine (with a python virtual environment) and it worked perfect! Your feedback was very helpful, could you please add answer instead of a comment so I can accept it like an answer for this post ? Thanks

Comment: @BilNash don't worry about it - you solved it personally - it is better for you to provide an answer to your own question - then accept it whenever the system lets you to do it. Don't forget to include the details of what you did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is something wrong in my windows environment. The code works fine in a debian based virtual machine and under a python virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the site automatically detects scrapers and blocks you. Try adding a small `sleep` statement somewhere to give their server some time to breathe. This is generally a polite thing to do while scraping anyway.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1) # pauses 1 second
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback bebop. I tried your trick but unfortunately I got the same behavior as before :(